# Do we have $|\delta_n(s)|\le |s|/n^{\sigma+1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n\in \Bbb N^*$ and $s=\sigma+it\in\Bbb C$, set $\delta_n(s)=\int_n^{n+1}[\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}]\,dx$, do we have $|\delta_n(s)|\le |s|/n^{\sigma+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

It holds for every $s$ that $$|\int_n^{n+1} (n^{-s}-x^{-s})dx| = |\int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s t^{-s-1}dtdx| \\ \le\int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x |s|\max(n^{-\Re(s)-1},(n+1)^{-\Re(s)-1})dtdx = \cases{ \frac{|s|}{2} n^{-\Re(s)-1} \text{ if } \Re(s) > -1 \\  \frac{|s|}{2} (n+1)^{-\Re(s)-1} \text{ otherwise }} $$